# 32 bit Wine in 64 bit PC running Ubuntu 64 bit Precise

Tags: 12.04, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

As I'm using dotnet20, I've setup a `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32` with `WINEARCH=win32` (as per question 'Installing dotnet2,0 on 64 bit machine'). I saw in above question (How to install 32 Bit Wine on 64 Bit Ubuntu) that to use the "Wine 32 bit version" permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add the following line:

```
WINEARCH=win32
```

Is this correct? I would have thought that it would be best to also add `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32`?

Answer (score 1):

You can install several wine versions including 64 and 32bit ones easily by using **playonlinux**. Playonlinux is a simple program providing you with as many wineprefixes as you like and for each of them you can choose a different version of wine.

You can install it via the Ubuntu software center or via command line (`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`) [or via any package management program you prefer].